# Error while getting multiple values from select cakephp

Tags: cakephp-3.0, multiple-select, multipleselection

I'm trying to get multiple values for store them in a database in cakephp 3.x but I cannot get all the values that I select. Just one.

In my view:

```
<select name="internalDestinations[ids]" id="internalDestinations-ids" multiple="true" class="...">
<?php
    foreach ($users2 as $i): ?>
       <option value="<?= $i['email'] ?>"> <?= $i['email'] ?> </option>
    <?php endforeach; 
    ?>
</select>
```

In my controller:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
     $alarm->internalDestinations=$this->request->data['internalDestinations']['ids'];
     $this->log($this->request->data['internalDestinations']);
}
```

And selecting more than one item in my input, I get just one:

```
Array
(
     [ids] => xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx
)
```

Any help? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do

```
name="internalDestinations[ids][]"
```

but why not using `FormHelper`?

```
//first of all let's create an array with email both in the keys and in the values

$users3 = Cake\Utility\Hash::combine($users2, '{n}.email', '{n}.email');

// then let's use cake dotted notation to create arrays

<?= $this->Form->input('internalDestinations.ids', [
        'type' => 'select', 
        'multiple' => true, 
        'options' => $users3
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: I don't know what internalDestinations is, and I don't know what you are trying to achieve. I showed you how to pass multiple values. If you are trying to save associated models take a look at the manual [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations) and [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data)

Comment: basic php: use [implode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.implode.php) function. But let me say that is a bad idea to store comma separated values into a single field.